# Log-linear model for contingency table with no fixed count

Tags: r, poisson-regression, log-linear, offset

I have table of counts of born children with four two-level factor variables (mother smoker/nonsmoker, child born dead/alive, ..). I would like to use log-linear model to understand interactions of the factors. For what I understand, I should use Poisson model, because there is no fixed count in the table. But Poisson regression requires offset and I do not think I have any. I would therefore to create saturated model in R use

```r
satmod <- glm( counts ~ (fact1 + fact2 + fact3 + fact4)^4, 
               family=poisson(link="log"))
```

but this is exactly what I would use for contingency table with fixed total count. I also tried

```r
satmod <- glm( counts ~ offset(log(rep(sum(counts), n))) + 
                (fact1 + fact2 + fact3 + fact4)^4, 
               family=poisson(link="log"))
```

with the offset set as a total number of counts for each variable, but I feel like this way I am saying that there was total of n*sum(counts) children, which is not true. So how am I supposed to model it? Isn't it, in the end, the same as contingency table with fixed total count?

Comment: - A Poisson model does not always require an offset, I do not see the need for it here
- Why can the total number of children not be considered fixed? What was the exact design of the experiment. Often conditioning on the total count is fine, depending on which inference you want to make.

Comment: Without offset I don't see any difference from the multinomial model. I suppose the data were collected during some period of time.